# Add Comment To JPEG in C#

Tags: c#, header, comments, jpeg, exif

Sorry for my English.

How I can add comment to Jpeg file to COM-marker section (0xFFFE)? Not a Exif
comment.

I try `Image.SetPropertyItem()` but it's save only first char of string.

Comment: Can you expand the question with an example code snippet which shows the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably have to use some metadata, for example, check out these two sites, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapmetadata.author.aspx), [dreamincode](http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet3144.htm).